# diplaying mathematical equtaions in android app

Tags: android

I am creating a **mathematics app** and have to display mathematical equations in my app. There are many answers related to this but I am not able to conclude how to do this?

Comment: I think you have to refer some Unicode for this or Refer https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView try this library

Comment: How to use this library, I am not able to understand how to use it, any guide related to this library can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above you can use that library MathView or other possibilities are ,

1. You can go with using the spannable string and can make superscripts
   and subscripts easily.
2. You can also use the HTML.fromHTML(String html) which will give you
   the spanned text and that you can set it to the TextView.
3. Or else show a webview and load the html page that contains the
   formulas and solutions. (This will be like creating a dynamic html
   files with in the app and showing it in the Webiew)

Comment: I am new to android development. Can u please elaborate the third point?